# directionsError event is not getting fired in bing maps

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm using the bing map to draw truck routes. But directionsError is never fired even when there does not exist any route for two locations.

```
 Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {
            directionsManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.DirectionsManager(map);
            directionsManager.setRequestOptions({
                routeMode: Microsoft.Maps.Directions.RouteMode.truck
            });
            //Create waypoints to route between.
            var waypointA = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: pickup_address });
            directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypointA);
            var waypointB = new Microsoft.Maps.Directions.Waypoint({ address: destination_address });
            directionsManager.addWaypoint(waypointB);
            //Add event handlers to directions manager.
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsError', directionsError);
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(directionsManager, 'directionsUpdated', directionsUpdated);
            //Calculate directions.
            directionsManager.calculateDirections();
  });

function directionsUpdated(e) {
        console.log(e);
}
    //---------------- Direction Error --------------//
function directionsError(e) {
        alert('Error: ' + e.message + '\r\nResponse Code: ' + e.responseCode)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a bug recently fixed since it's no longer reproduced on Bing Maps **experimental** branch.

In this sample, update RouteMode to truck and re-run it, the error message will be displayed as "No solution".
https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol/isdk/directionsevent_directionserror?autoRedirect=false
[image]